# Javascript - Separar uma string e então somar os valores

Tags: javascript

Estou iniciando em javascript e me deparei com uma dúvida. Eu preciso que o usuário coloque sua data de nascimento, que eu vou armazenar dia, mês e ano em variavéis diferentes. O que eu preciso é separar os valores dessas variáveis e então efetuar uma soma com eles.

Por exemplo, o usuário insere que o ano de nascimento é 1994, então eu preciso que meu programa faça 1 + 9 + 9 + 4 = 23, que será armazenado na variável do ano.

Obrigado!

Comment: Oi Lucas, o que você já tentou? Poderia atualizar sua questão com o código relevante?

Comment: Você já possui algo implementado para que possamos trabalhar com isso ? O campo que o usuário irá colocar será text, date ? Por favor, coloque mais informações para deixar um pouco mais claro o cenário, porque dependo das respostas a solução pode mudar

Comment: Estou pelo celular agora e não consigo acessar o que eu estava tentando para postar agora. Mas o campo que o usuário coloca é armazenado como string, com uma validação a respeito se o formato está correto:  dia e mês com dois algarismos e ano com quatro.

Comment: Qual é o objetivo de somar cada digito do ano ? Como vai obter o ano de volta depois desse calculo ?

Comment: Oi Issac, em cada etapa do programa ele reduz(soma os algarismos) o maior valor, da direita para a esquerda, entre o dia, mês e ano,  até que a soma desses seja menor ou igual a 22 e por fim ele associa esse número com uma "sorte".

Answer (score 1):

Quase assim:

```
var str = "1 + 4 + 5";
str = str.repalce(" ",""); //remove os espaços
str = str.split("+"); //transforma a str em array (lista)
for (i=0; i<str.length; i++){ //percorre a lista
    str[i] = parseInt(str[i]); //transforma os valores em inteiros
}
```

Agora vc terá uma lista de inteiros. Código para soma de lista:

```
function soma(lista){
    var total = 0;
    for (i=0; i<lista.length; i++){
        total += lista[i];
    }
    return total;
}
```

Execute assim:

```
soma(str);
```

Answer (score 1):

Uma outra saída é usar o [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce):

```
'1994'.split('').reduce((sum, x) => parseInt(x) + parseInt(sum)) // 23
```